# my whole computer is now linked with git trying to link an existing R project MAC

Tags: git, github, rstudio

Hi I ran into a problem when I tried to link a regular R Project with Git. Here's the break down:

1. In terminal I managed to find the directory ~cd...
2. git init worked
3. "git add ." worked but here's where I ran into the problem. Terminal started asking for permissions to access documents, downloads, pictures (Seriously? but why?) and I kept pressing "dont allow". Terminal stopped working and I quit Terminal.
4. Then on one of the discussion threads I came across with this link https://happygitwithr.com/existing-github-last.html
5. In short I logged-in to my Git Hub account, went to Repo, and uploaded the R Project that was not under version control. Upload was successful but nothing changed in R Studio. So I restarted R Studio and viola, there is "Git" Tab in environment window. Now the bigger problem!
6. When I clicked the Git tab I could see my directory for pictures, downloads, movies basically every major directory on my MAC. Luckily my repo is private so hopefully no one will be able access pictures and what not. No sure how much of it has been put on the repo. On Git Hub I could only see my newly uploaded RProj and R Scripts from the past

Why did it happen? and what do I do next? Any thoughts, comments?

Screenshot of RStudio;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It all depends *where* you did `git init .`

If you did it in `~` (`$HOME`, that is `/home/<you>`), meaning if you see a `/home/<you>/.git/` folder, that would explain why Git had to access all those directories (Pictures, Music, ...)

Simply remove that folder, and do a `git init .` in the actual folder where you have your R project.